# Add a file.exe to be copy ffrom task devops

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

task: CopyFiles@2
inputs:
sourceFolder: 'source/bin/Release/net6.0'
contents: |
file.exe
targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/file/file'

Hi, I want on devops under my yaml file to be able to copy my .exe file. but I can't see it when I create my build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to confirm that the .exe file really exists in the directory(Please make sure the repository and the branch are both correct.), and after that, the below YAML definition can help you check whether the file has been copied successfully.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/source/bin/Release/net6.0'
    Contents: '**.exe'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/file/file'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/file/file'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

After run the pipeline, you can check this place to judge whether the copy operation works fine:

[image]

[image]

My repository structure:

[image]

Comment: Hi, forgot to close this one cause I solved it. Thank you for your response!